# What was the Early Church's view of sexual immorality and sex outside of marriage?

Tags: sin, early-church, marriage, church-fathers, sexuality

What was the early church's perspective of sexual immorality and sex outside of marriage? I know the biblical perspective, but I am incredibly interested in how the early church fathers viewed this issue and would greatly appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to distinguish between the early church's view and the Biblical view. Acts 15 discusses the Jerusalem counsel, where the Apostle James says:

> 19 Therefore my judgment is that we should not trouble those of the
> Gentiles who turn to God, 20 but should write to them to abstain from
> the things polluted by idols, and from sexual immorality, and from
> what has been strangled, and from blood. 21 For from ancient
> generations Moses has had in every city those who proclaim him, for he
> is read every Sabbath in the synagogues.”

Later in that chapter, James' words are adopted and given to Paul and Barnabas to disseminate, and Judas and Silas to authenticate:

> 25 it has seemed good to us, having come to one accord, to choose men
> and send them to you with our beloved Barnabas and Paul, 26 men who
> have risked their lives for the name of our Lord Jesus Christ. 27 We
> have therefore sent Judas and Silas, who themselves will tell you the
> same things by word of mouth. 28 For it has seemed good to the Holy
> Spirit and to us to lay on you no greater burden than these
> requirements: 29 that you abstain from what has been sacrificed to
> idols, and from blood, and from what has been strangled, and from
> sexual immorality. If you keep yourselves from these, you will do
> well. Farewell.”

Later in Acts, this is repeated:

> 25 But as for the Gentiles who have believed, we have sent a letter
> with our judgment that they should abstain from what has been
> sacrificed to idols, and from blood, and from what has been
> strangled, and from sexual immorality.” (Acts 21:25)

This would mean that the Jewish definitions and rules for sexual immorality would apply to Gentile believers.

This article comments on the progression of these ideas:

https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/blogs/kevin-deyoung/first-sexual-revolution-triumph-christian-morality-roman-empire/

The article states:

> The Christian sexual revolution became codified in law under the reign
> of Justinian (527-565).

One earlier source cited is Chrysostom.

Comment: Evidence using quotations from early church fathers, preferably the apostolic fathers, seem necessary to answer this question.  Maybe *Didache* have it?